# Feasibility of grouping tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to be able to group tabs in Chrome (on Windows Vista/7 primarily), as I can with Tab Mix Plus on Firefox, so that I only see one group in the tab list at one time. I don't seem to be the only one, but it hasn't been done, so far as I can tell. There are plenty of tab managers out there, like TooManyTabs and Tab Outliner, which summarise, save and unload tabs, but they don't leave them loaded whilst hiding them.

I've not coded a Chrome extension before, but I think the specific problem is that you can't control the visibility of tabs (in the way you can with the hidden attribute of tabs in Firefox) or windows from a Chrome extension. Is that right, or have I missed something in the API?

If that is right, any way anyone can see to hack round this? Put the tabs I want invisible in a window and then use whatever Windows API allows http://www.hide-window.com/ to hide that window?

Comment: You're right, there's no "hidden" attribute. I can think of a solution: Create a new non-focused window, and move the tab(s) to it.

Comment: That could be read as facetious ;-)

Fair enough if it is. Perhaps no tool is needed for most people. However, switching tabs is something I do 1000 times a day, so I think it's worth a good tool.

It could also be read as a serious suggestion as to how to implement this (as I suggested in my third parag, but with just unfocused windows. Unfortunately for that idea, I also Alt-Tab 1000 times a day, so I want to minimise the number of windows.

Maybe what I need is a better Alt-Tab though!